# How to use external scripts using node modules

Tags: node.js

I have a questions.js file. It contains the following code

```
module.exports.q1 = "function sum(arr) { \n var answer = 0; \n } \n sum([1, 2]);";
```

I have an index.js file. It contains the following code.

```
var questions = require('./questions.js');

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
   console.log(questions.q1);
});
```

When I start node index.js I successfully console.log the contents of index.js

I also have an index.html file. I've been writing most of my JavaScript in script tags in the index.html because I'm not sure how to use external scripts.

Inside of index.js, I can use the require() functionality, but I cant use document.getElementById('myTextArea').value to assign the value of questions.q1 to my textarea.

Meanwhile, inside of index.html and within my script tags, I can use functionality like document.getElementById and jquery, but I can not use the require() functionality.

**My specific question is** how do I take a string stored in questions.js, and assign that value to my textarea?

Comment: Are you writing Node code or browser code? These are two different worlds.

Comment: Your question is too broad. How are you serving `index.html`? Are you using express.js? You need a way to pass variables to your "view" on the server, you don't need to require them from the client.

Comment: Serving my index.html like this app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');